# Forcing a stream to read binary data / data in specific encoding

Tags: python, stream

I have a data stream that contains data encoded in windows-1251 encoding. In C#, I can easily read some data from the stream like this:

```
private static void ReadStream(Stream stream)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), true, 1024, true)
    {
        // read from stream
    }
}

// usage
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.txt"))
{
    ReadStream(fileStream);
}
```

But in Python, the concepts of `Stream` and `StreamReader` are merged into one class. Suppose I have a code like this:

```
def read_stream(stream):
    # read from stream
    pass

# usage
with open(r'C:\test.txt') as file_stream:
    read_stream(file_stream)
```

If I'm inside a `read_stream` function, I have no idea if the stream was opened in binary mode or in text mode (and which encoding is used in the later case). Is there any way to 'reopen' the stream with the encoding that I want (windows-1251)?

**EDIT**: I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? The differences matter here.

Comment: @duskwuff I'm using Python 3.5